# How to build .DLL for Oracle UDTs in BizTalk?

Tags: oracle, biztalk, biztalk-2020

We have .DLLs from BizTalk 2016 that work.  I want to regenerate them for BizTalk 2020 and a different version of the Oracle adapter. I've been told that if the stored procs use User Defined Types (UDTs) then you have to create a .DLL.  (This .DLL is specified in the WCF-Custom Send Port bindings in the UserAssembliesLoadPath property.)

What is the process to create these .DLLs, and where is that process documented?

I have run the "Consume Adapter" and "Add Adapter" connecting to an Oracle server and stored procedure that uses User-Defined-Types (UDTs).
Although it generates schemas, it has not generated any DLLs, and I don't see any option to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Support for Oracle User-Defined Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-oracle-ebs/support-for-oracle-user-defined-types2#design-time), Design Time

> You must perform these steps while generation schema for the operation in Visual Studio.

> 1. Connect to Oracle E-Business Suite (or Oracle DB) using the Consume Adapter Service Add-in, the Add Adapter Metadata Wizard, or the Add Adapter Service Reference Plug-in. For information about doing so, see Connect to the Oracle E-Business Suite in Visual Studio.
> 2. While connecting, in the Binding Properties tab of the Configure Adapter dialog box, specify appropriate values for the GeneratedUserTypesAssemblyFilePath and GeneratedUserTypesAssemblyKeyFilePath binding properties. For information about these binding properties, see Read about BizTalk Adapter for Oracle E-Business Suite Binding Properties.

[image]

> 3. When you are connected to Oracle E-Business Suite in Visual Studio, browse to the required artifact that contains an Oracle UDT. For information about browsing artifacts, see Browse, Search, and Retrieve Metadata for Oracle E-Business Operations.
> 4. Select the required artifact, and then click OK. The Oracle E-Business adapter generates the metadata for the selected operation along with the assembly (.dll file) for the Oracle UDT in the selected artifact. The assembly is created at the location that you specified in the GeneratedUserTypesAssemblyFilePath binding property.
> 5. Proceed with the rest of the steps for building and deploying your project.

Comment: Thanks, seems like I did that, but I will try again with your steps.  Also - what's the difference between Oracle E-Business Suite and Oracle DB? I tried both already, and both seemed to do the same.   Do you have to use the E-Business Suite instead of DB if UDT's involved?

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I didn't realize that you had to go to the "Bindings Properties" and fill in those two properties.  I used OracleDB, not Oracle ESB.  I haven't tested the .dll yet, that's next.

Comment: Also note - if you get ORA-01013, that is basically a timeout.  You can change the timeouts in the BindingProperties and apparently they apply to the generator tool (not just runtime).